# Linearlayout weights not giving what I write

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

So I want to have a headline that is ALWAYS a third of the screen and then the rest of the 2 thirds of the screen with names. Seems easy but the result is that the headline becomes less than a third if there is many names. It is only 2 lines that does this I wrtite //1 //2 to easily find them but give the whole code since it may affect the result.

Here is a photo.
[The top text does not show the whole message and Is not 1 third of the screen as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVAdC.png)
Thanks in advance!

```
    private void showScores() {
    float baseTextSize = 100/playerNum;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            10000.0f  //1
    );
    TextView t = new TextView(this);
    String result_msg = getString(R.string.result_msg);
    t.setLayoutParams(param);
    t.setText(result_msg + "\n");
    t.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.white));
    if (playerNum>3) {
        t.setTextSize(30f);
    } else {
        t.setTextSize(40f);
    }
    scoreShower.addView(t);
    param.weight = 20000.0f/playerNum;  //2
    for (int i=0;i<playerNum;i++) {
        TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        txt.setLayoutParams(param);
        if (i == 0) {
            txt.setTextSize(baseTextSize + 8f);
            txt.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.gold));
        } else {
            txt.setTextSize(baseTextSize);
            txt.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.white));
        }
        String txtString = (i+1) + ". " + arrayList.get(i).getKey() + " : " + arrayList.get(i).getValue();
        txt.setText(txtString);
        if (playerNum>6) {
            txt.setTextSize(10f);
        }
        scoreShower.addView(txt);
    }
```

Comment: Adding param.height=0 did not help. Added a photo of the result, click on the blue text

Answer (score 0):

Try using weighted LinearLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
       ....
       ...weightSum="3"
       ...orientation="vertical">
```

Set the weight of the top view to 2 using

```
<...
   ...layout_weight="1">
```

And the one below set the weight to 2

Comment: I am adding my items dynamically and tried weight sum but it did not work unfortunately ty anyways

Comment: Are you adding the items dynamically to a listview or recyclerview?